# How to properly initialize the data members in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, styles

In C++11, we have two ways to initialize the data members of a class/struct as illustrated in the following examples:

```
struct A
{
    int n = 7;
};

struct B
{
    int n;

    B() : n(7) {}
};
```

**Question 1:**

Which way is better?

**Question 2:**

Is the traditional way (the latter) not encouraged from the view of a modern-C++-style checker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually *mix* both styles. This is useful if you have multiple constructors, but the variables is only specifically initialized by one or a few of the constructors.

Example

```
struct A
{
    int n = 7;

    A() {}  // n will be initialized to 7
    A(int n_): n{n_} {}  // Initialize n to something else
};
```

Comment: I am not sure, whether the n{n_} is mistake, or not? Is it possible to use initializer notation in constructor as well?

Comment: one more thing, when using Initializer list may cause some overhead, if I am right. I would avoid using in case you have to deal with limited resources.

Comment: You're missing a colon here: `A(int n_) : n{_n} {}`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I think that the first case is possible only with C++ primitive types. In most of the books, especially in book 55 Ways to improve your C++ code by Scott Meyers, it is recommended to go via first way, so I would stick with that. :-)

Don't forget, that order of evaluation and initialization is determined how members in classes are sorted.

I prefer just the second style of initialization.

Comment: That book was written in 2005, which is 6 years before 2011. so the author don't know the new initialization method.

Comment: Well, they have made new edition. I don't say, it's 100% accurate, but some C++11 elements are there, 14 is absent completely. :-) Even though, it is old, a lot of concepts are still valid.

Comment: Oops, I don't know that. and completely missed your answer. forgive me.

Comment: Actually, the first method here is called "uniform initialization" and is not restricted to primitives; You can construct objects all you want with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Neither way is better, however, the new uniform initialization has the perk of being similar to other languages and over-all more understandable. Uniform initialization does not only apply to struct members, but also across the board for initializer lists and constructor arguments.